# What is the difference between "Video Graphic Adapter" and "Video Graphic Array"

Tags: arrays, graphics, adapter, vga

I'm bit confused that what is the difference between "Adapter" and "Array". Some Graphics oriented expressions include the first and other the second. Such as:

In VGA it's array:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array

In CGA it's adapter:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter

When I see somewhere "video graphic adapter" is it a misuse?
Could you explain the difference? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe add a link about how you got the idea that it means adapter? Adapter is generic, array is the VGA standard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited the question!

Comment: So read the wiki you posted. :) It's arbitrary words. Both VGA and CGA could use different connectors. VGA being later maybe went with array to avoid some of that confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got the answer, and it's very simple.

The array is the "connector", this one:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/DE15_Connector_Pinout.svg/337px-DE15_Connector_Pinout.svg.png

This made my confusion. On some sources I found "video graphic adapters", and in fact, it exists such as "super video graphic adapter" - SVGA. But here now we aren't talking about the connector with pins, but the "generic" that @starmole mentioned.